# disabled button seems enabled

Tags: html, button, seam

Using jboss 4.2.0 and deploying a Seam project war, I have a problem with html's commandButton disabled attribute.

The buttons seem enabled although their disabled attribute are set to true. The following three butons look al the same, but only "Back" button works as expected. The other other two looks enabled and when I click on them nothing happens.I couldn't figure out why  they look enabled.

```
<h:commandButton value="Back" action="/bbaa.seam" />
<h:commandButton value="Edit"
                disabled="#{bbg.btnEditDisabled}"
                action="#{bbg.edit()}"
                rendered="#{bbg.btnEditRendered}" />
<h:commandButton value="Save"
                disabled="#{bbg.btnSaveDisabled}"
                action="#{bbg.save()}"
                rendered="#{bbg.btnSaveRendered}" />
```

This is what I see when I inspect the elements:

```
 <input type="submit" name="bbgForm:j_id609" value="Back">
    <input type="submit" name="bbgForm:j_id610" value="Edit"         disabled="disabled">
    <input type="submit" name="bbgForm:j_id611" value="Save" disabled="disabled">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this...

```
   <input type="submit" name="bbgFormid611" value="Save" disabled>
```

Use jquery

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
disable: function(state) {
    return this.each(function() {
        this.disabled = state;
    });
}});
```

Otherwis

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css pseudoclass :disabled to change the appearance of 'disabled' elements ... like

```
input[type=submit]:disabled {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**note** : IE does not support this in older versions (as far as i know <= 9).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It made me investigate the issue deeper.I found that in the live system, the inspected sytle  shows      input[type="submit"][disabled] 
definition, and the buttons DO look disabled.
Yet in the testing environment, I  see  only  input[type="submit"]  definitions, no [disabled] related style info appears.
I've checked  our projects css files and all I found is 
<u:selector name="input[type=submit][disabled], input[type=button][disabled]">
  <u:style name="opacity" value="0.33"/>
 </u:selector> 
    
Where should I look for 'disabled' style definiton?

Comment: you seem to use RichFaces ... unfortunately i don't know the XCSS Format they use ... from what i understand from your selector and style i would expect the disabled button to have an opacity of 1/3. 
why the buttons behave differently on different stages i can't tell from here ... maybe there are some more css rules active in your testing environment that override the 'disabled' look ?

Comment: yes you're right, I use RichFaces, sorry for not mentioning in the first place.
This overriding issue could be the cause since in the test environment(inspected in Chrome this time) I see  input[type=submit][disabled]   definiton, yet the definiton looks passive to me (it has a grey backgorund color) 
Thanks for your comments:)